# Javascript form validation for date not working

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript running on a html form. really struggling to get this working, Nothing pops up, no alerts at all. any help please. My code is probably terrible but I have only been using javascript for 4 weeks

```
    function validate(form){

var vRunnerId = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["RunnerId"].value;
var vEventId = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["EventId"].value;
var vDate = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["Date"].value;
var vFinishTime = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["FinishTime"].value;
var vPosition = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["Position"].value;
var vCategoryId = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["CategoryId"].value;
var vAgeGrade = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["AgeGrade"].value;
var vPB = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["PB"].value;
var validFormat = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;

    if (/\D/.test(vRunnerId)){
      alert("Please only enter numeric characters only for your Runner ID");
      return false;
      }

    if (/\D/.test(vEventId)){
      alert("Please only enter numeric characters only for your Event ID");
      return false;
      }

    if (!validFormat.test(vDate){
      alert("Please enter date in YYYY-MM-DD");
      return false;
      }

      return true;
}
```

Comment: is this a valid date `2014-07-78` :)

Comment: The variable vDate already holds the value from the Date field. You should be simply doing `!validFormat.test(vDate)`. Moreover, `2014-07-78` isn't a valid date. You'll need to refine your regex further for date validations.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to remove the entire original content when you've received a satisfactory answer - anyone with a similar problem would still like to be able to search based on your original question to see what useful answers were given.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `vDate` being defined anywhere in that function, so it looks like you forgot to add that to your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are grabbing the `<input>` value twice. Once here:

```
var vDate = document.forms["submitrunnertime"]["Date"].value;
```

and again in the check:

```
if (!validFormat.test(vDate.value)){
```

You're trying to find the `.value` of a `.value` which I would assumed would throw en error.